# How do I prevent CSS 3D transformed elements from extending the page?

Tags: css

In my CSS parallax, I'm setting the `<body>` and `<html>` as follows:

```
@supports (perspective: 1px) { /* The parallax atmosphere */
  html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  html > body {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  html > body:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Here's an example of the CSS for one of the parallax layers within (the important part):

```
#aF-background-layer-1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden; /* Because it wraps an SVG */
}
@supports (perspective: 1px) {
  #aF-background-layer-1 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-72px) scale(73);
    transform: translateZ(-72px) scale(73);
    will-change: transform;
  }
}
```

There's more CSS, but that is just to give the layers their dimensions, colors, how to treat the SVGs inside and it all works beautifully. The problem is when you scroll to the bottom of the page. In Chrome scrolling stops when you reach the bottom of the `<body>`. In FireFox and Safari (not sure about IE/Edge or others), scrolling doesn't stop until you've reached to bottom of all elements. This can last for quite some distance if any of the elements are very far off in the distance (moving very slowly on scroll). So the question is:

**How do I stop scrolling at the end of the `<body>`?**

I can't just use `overflow: hidden;` on the `<body>` as the page won't even scroll. I prefer to do this with CSS, not JS. Here is a sandbox to play in:

https://codepen.io/joerhoney/pen/yRmeOL

Answer (score 0):

In your html head specifying height as 200vh:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" height="200vh" user-scalable="yes" initial-scale="1.0">
</head>
```

change the height on the html and body in your css:

```
html {
    height: 200vh;
}

html > body {
    height: 200vh;
}
```

I'm not sure these are the numbers you want, but you need them to match up.

https://codepen.io/carolmckayau/pen/EdqwmL

Comment: Thank you for that, but it doesn't work in this case. In Chrome, scrolling stops short, so you can't get to the bottom of the `<body>`, while other browsers still allow you to scroll beyond the end of the `<body>`. Actually, I need the content on the page to play its role in the calculation of the page height too. It seems that setting a height on the `<body>` would only restrict that. I don't want to vote this answer down though, as it was a sincere and good attempt, and it may be useful for someone else.

Comment: **Correction**: FireFox now stops short of scrolling the `<body>`, just like Chrome (which is not what we want in either case). Safari still allows scrolling beyond the end of the `<body>` (which we don't want either).